# Tomcat - won't load my META-INF\services\javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer file?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat

I have a web project that has a `\META-INF\services\javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file with its content pointing to the fully qualified name of a class that implements the ServletContainerInitializer interface. I basically followed the example given here: http://nullhaus.com/2011/03/using-servlets-3-0-servletcontainerinitializer/

I put debug lines in my class that implements the ServletContainerInitializer interface and it never makes it there. Not even the default constructor...

My application folder structure is as follows:

```
\MyApp
      \META-INF\services\javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
      \WEB-INF\classes\
                 ... [list of classes and packages go here]
```

Any ideas what I need to check for??

Note 1: My Tomcat publishes from an exploded external folder that contains my application

Note 2: I started my Tomcat from Eclipse - if that makes a difference!

Comment: are you still experiencing problems with this ServletContainerInitializer?

Comment: yes, I gave up and decided to go for a different approach... very annoying however because it doesn't make sense as to why it wouldn't work. Are you having the same issue as well?

Comment: no I don't. I'm just the author of the blog you've mentioned in your post, that's why I am curious if I could help you with this :-)

Comment: ah, thank you. Well it seems so straightforward, and it should be but no matter what I tried it just wouldn't fire off. It's as if the javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer file isn't even there. I was able to gte it semi working on JBoss so I know for a fact that it isn't an issue with how my war file was setup but something to do with how Tomcat scans the services folder.

Comment: and what Tomcat did you use? I'll try to set up the environment you're using.

Comment: And second, more important question, did you try wrapping whole project into *.jar and deploying it in the tomcat?

Comment: I was using Tomcat 7.0 - basically the latest at the time I wrote the question. I think I also tried 6.x and same thing. My project was a war file, incase the war I have the structure outline by my question above. I didn't try wrapping the whole project into a *.jar....

Comment: sorry mate, I meant *.war - not *.jar :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think that you'll need to wrap your initializer class (and it's services-related META-INF directory) into a separate *.jar and put it in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

This is a JAR service, so I guess it could have something to do with problems with discovering services in a *.war file. Moreover, it **doesn't** even help if you put your META-INF directory inside `WEB-INF/classes` and set `unpackWAR=false` in your Tomcat's `server.xml`.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. That would explain the behavior.. What I do find odd however is that JBoss *does* seem to work with my setup and can discover services inside the Services folder even if you don't have them wrapped in a Jar file... but Tomcat doesn't! Anyway, thank you for that.

Comment: Glad I could help. When you say that the JBoss found the services - where did you put the 'services' directory in the application? Was it inside `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` or inside `META-INF` on the same level as `WEB-INF`?

Comment: I confirm this answer. Both the class and the META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
 definition file must be in a separate .jar file in WEB-INF/lib. Putting META-INF/services in the WAR file in either /META-INF/services or WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services does not work.

Comment: Further to this, if the JAR file concerned is placed in Tomcat's own lib directory it can see all context initializations. If it is placed in a web-app's WEB-INF/lib directory it can only see that web-app's context initializations.

Comment: Spring Framework 3.1 provides a nice solution to packaging the jar oneself.  spring-web-VERSION.jar contains a `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation and includes the `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file that instructs the container to load `org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer`.  The `SpringServletContainerInitializer` will then load any classes extending Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` interface.  Additionally, `WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup` is a simpler interface to implement than `ServletContainerInitializer#onStartup`.

Answer (score 5):

For tomcat to load the **META-INF** directory , it has to be in classes folder . If you are using maven project , just put the META-INF directory inside **src/main/resources** directory .. on mvn package the same will be copied to classes directory .. No need of separerate jar .. if jar is prefered you can use 
**HandlesTypes** annotation ..

Comment: Same here, Process Monitor on Windows clearly shows that e.g. Tomcat 7.0.90 is scanning for `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/[...]`. `META-INF` at the same level of `WEB-INF` doesn't seem to be used at all.

Comment: My former statement is true for Tomcat used within and stand-alone outside Eclipse, tested both.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to check is that you are actually using Servlet 3.0 and not an earlier version. For Tomcat, this means that you must be using Tomcat 7.0.22

Second, make sure that the \META-INF\services\javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer file actually exists in the exploded war file.

Third, when in doubt, configure and start Tomcat directly (not from Eclipse) - I've seen developers have endless problems with configuration of Tomcat using the Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to quote some good explanation from `Mark Thomas <markt@apache.org>` given on the user mailing list of Tomcat:

> Service files are loaded by class loaders from the META-INF/services
>   directory.
>
> *.jar!/META-INF/services
>   and
>   *.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services
>   are visible to class loaders
>
> *.war!/META-INF/services
>   is not.
>
> The servlet expert group recently discussed WAR vs JAR in the context of
>   Java 9 and mutli-version JARs. The conclusion was (I'm paraphrasing)
>   that WARs are not a specialised form of JAR and while they share a
>   common format a feature that is available to a JAR is NOT automatically
>   available to a WAR unless the Servlet spec (of Java EE spec) explicitly
>   states otherwise.
>
> Containers are free to add container specific extensions if they wish
>   but they come with the usual (lack of) interoperability warnings.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201808.mbox/