# Injecting a Spring dependency into a JPA EntityListener

Tags: spring, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-roo, entitylisteners

I am trying **to inject a Spring dependency** into an **JPA EntityListener**. Here is my listener class:

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck = true)
public class PliListener {

    @Autowired
    private EvenementPliRepository evenementPliRepository;

    @PostPersist
    void onPostPersist(Pli pli) {
        EvenementPli ev = new EvenementPli();
        ev.setPli(pli);
        ev.setDateCreation(new Date());
        ev.setType(TypeEvenement.creation);
        ev.setMessage("Création d'un pli");
        System.out.println("evenementPliRepository: " + evenementPliRepository);
        evenementPliRepository.save(ev);
    }


}
```

Here is my Entity class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@EntityListeners(PliListener.class)
public class Pli implements Serializable{
...
```

However, my dependency (i.e. `evenementPliRepository`) **is always null**.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616146/eventlisteners-using-hibernate-4-0-with-spring-3-1-0-release

Comment: I was also facing the same problem and found a solution and have answered it on another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171221/how-to-inject-entitymanager-in-entitylisteners/42222592#42222592

Comment: For anyone interested, I just tried Spring (5.1.9) Boot (2.1.8) and JPA Event Listener integration and it works perfectly fine now, all without any hacks or work arounds. I'm not sure how that is possible, but perhaps it has to do with the Resolver that is used for Validation as well.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell

I do constructor inject, it cause a "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle", I do other way it doesn't work. I am pretty sure about the version of spring boot(org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.6.RELEASE) and hibernate(org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.12.Final) version

Answer (score 50):

A hack to inject dependencies on stateless beans, is to define the dependency as "static", create a setter method so that Spring can inject the dependency (assigning it to the static dependency).

Declare the dependency as static.

```
static private EvenementPliRepository evenementPliRepository;
```

Create a method so that Spring can inject it.

```
@Autowired
public void init(EvenementPliRepository evenementPliRepository) 
{
    MyListenerClass.evenementPliRepository = evenementPliRepository;
    logger.info("Initializing with dependency ["+ evenementPliRepository +"]"); 
}
```

More details at: http://blog-en.lineofsightnet.com/2012/08/dependency-injection-on-stateless-beans.html

Comment: The listener class must be annotated with `@Component` (or similar) for this to work

Comment: tried this solution to inject entity B's repository into an entity A's entity listener class. However, when entity B's repository method (e.g. `findAll()`) is called, below exception is returned:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1043)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:997)
 at 
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
`

Answer (score 32):

This is actually an old question but I found an alternative solution :

```
public class MyEntityListener {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(MyEntity target) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        publisher.publishEvent(new OnCreatedEvent<>(this, target));
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate(MyEntity target) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        publisher.publishEvent(new OnUpdatedEvent<>(this, target));
    }

    @PostRemove
    public void postDelete(MyEntity target) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        publisher.publishEvent(new OnDeletedEvent<>(this, target));
    }
}
```

Probably not the best one but better than static variables w/o AOP + weaving.

Comment: And how to attach that listener to actual entity without using xml??

Comment: Add `@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)` on the related entity.

Comment: Cannot do - model is in separate JAR. What I meant is to how to do that without XML on runtime.

Comment: This is already a XML-less solution. You should include this to your jar that contains entities. Or maybe create a shared jar. If you don't have access to model's sources, you probably have to extend each class you want to listen.

Comment: Tried this but did not work for me. See the debug message from "processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext()" method: Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of MyEntityListener: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Just a bit worried about possible performance issues since as the method name says it process the injections again

Comment: I think there's another solution which is based on `@Configurable` but I don't have tried yet.

Comment: The part ` SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` should not be executed again and again. It would be better to wrap the call into an test using a instance boolean to check if the DI already was executed.

Comment: this is a good solution, the only change I had make is call processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext once in the constructor.

Comment: You know in which case `insert` still always trigger `PostUpdate` and never `PostPersist`?

Comment: Did not work for me either. Getting the same error as someone mentioned above: "Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of MyEntityListener: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection."

Answer (score 23):

I annotated the listener with **@Component** annotation, then created a **non static setter** to assign the injected Spring bean, it works well

My code looks like :

```
@Component
public class EntityListener {

    private static MyService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyService (MyService service) {
        this.service=service;
    }


    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate() {

        service.doThings()

    }

    @PrePersist
    public void onPersist() {
       ...
    }


}
```

Comment: maybe EntityListener.service=service would be better than this.service=service

Comment: it works for me. but can you please explain more. I am not able to understand why using static dependency it worked.

Comment: The reason is that JPA creates the instance without doing dependency injection, then later Spring creates an instance on its own and sets the autowired dependency, which sets the static variable, enabling all instances to use the MyService instance.

Comment: This solution is hack, which leaded to need of adding @DirtiesContext to my tests. This happens probably because the listener is using different instance of MyService then rest of the spring context. EclipseAce's solution works perfectly fine. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60968523/2521628)

Comment: It works, although I do not like to have this static field

Answer (score 21):

Since Spring V5.1 (and Hibernate V5.3) it should work out of the box as Spring registers as the provider of those classes.
see documentation of [SpringBeanContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html)

Comment: In my opinion, it is most natural way for newer Hibernate versions, this answer is the best and has to be accepted one, as Hibernate 5.3+ becomes more and more widely used. @drenda, pls. check out your Hibernate version, it's Hibernate version that matters, not Spring Boot one. In a case you have your Hibernate version overwritten and you happen to use older version, check out my answer.

Comment: But what is the solution?  You mean the listener with `@Configurable` and the `@Autowired` attribute as posted on the question should work with Hibernate 5.3+?  Please clarify.

Comment: On Hibernate 6.x (and Spring Boot 3.x) i had to set `hibernate.resource.beans.container` property manually as in provided link and `@Autowired` started working as expected in listener as in question.

Comment: I now have the problem that my Autowired bean is null in a SpringBootTest in spring boot 3.2 .Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 18):

try use `ObjectFactory` like this

```java
@Configurable
public class YourEntityListener {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<YourBean> yourBeanProvider;

    @PrePersist
    public void beforePersist(Object target) {
       YourBean yourBean = yourBeanProvider.getObject();
       // do somthing with yourBean here
    }
}
```

I found this solution in `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener` from spring-data-jpa.

demo: https://github.com/eclipseAce/inject-into-entity-listener

Comment: I wrote a demo for that, please check out

Comment: @eclipseAce , I'm getting null pointer exception, exactly I wrote exact the same code just changed service name to my service

Answer (score 16):

And what about this solution?

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AbstractEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column(name = "modification_date")
    private Date modificationDate;

}
```

Then the Listener...

```
@Component
public class AbstractEntityListener {

    @Autowired
    private DateTimeService dateTimeService;

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(AbstractEntity abstractEntity) {
        AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.dateTimeService);
            abstractEntity.setModificationDate(this.dateTimeService.getCurrentDate());
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(AbstractEntity abstractEntity) {
        AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.dateTimeService);
        Date currentDate = this.dateTimeService.getCurrentDate();
        abstractEntity.setCreationDate(currentDate);
        abstractEntity.setModificationDate(currentDate);
    }
}
```

And the helper...

```
    /**
     * Helper class which is able to autowire a specified class. It holds a static reference to the {@link org
     * .springframework.context.ApplicationContext}.
     */
    public final class AutowireHelper implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private static final AutowireHelper INSTANCE = new AutowireHelper();
        private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        private AutowireHelper() {
        }

        /**
         * Tries to autowire the specified instance of the class if one of the specified beans which need to be autowired
         * are null.
         *
         * @param classToAutowire the instance of the class which holds @Autowire annotations
         * @param beansToAutowireInClass the beans which have the @Autowire annotation in the specified {#classToAutowire}
         */
        public static void autowire(Object classToAutowire, Object... beansToAutowireInClass) {
            for (Object bean : beansToAutowireInClass) {
                if (bean == null) {
                    applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(classToAutowire);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            AutowireHelper.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        /**
         * @return the singleton instance.
         */
        public static AutowireHelper getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }

    }
```

Works for me.

Source:
http://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/

Comment: There is a gotcha with this solution if the EntityListener is used in the initialization of ApplicationContext itself; then you must make sure that the `AutowireHelper` bean is initialized before the code that uses it.

Comment: Works, but only after you register the AutowireHelper in the config xml or Java Spring configuration:  
@Bean
public AutowireHelper autowireHelper(){
    return AutowireHelper.getInstance();
}

Comment: what about @EntityListeners(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.class)

Answer (score 14):

I started to go down the path of using AOP to inject a spring bean into an Entity listener. After a day and a half of research and trying different things I came across this [link](http://www.simonellistonball.com/technology/injecting-dependencies-into-a-jpa-entitylistener) which stated:

> It is not possible to inject spring managed beans into a JPA EntityListener class. This is because the JPA listener mechanism should be based on a stateless class, so the methods are effectively static, and non-context aware.  ... No amount of AOP will save you, nothing gets injected to the ‘object’ representing the listener, because the implementations don’t actually create instances, but uses the class method.

At this point I regrouped and stumbled across the EclipseLink [DescriptorEventAdapter](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorEventAdapter.html).  Using this information I created a listener class that extended the Descriptor Adapter.

```
public class EntityListener extends DescriptorEventAdapter {
    private String injectedValue;

    public void setInjectedValue(String value){
        this.injectedValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void aboutToInsert(DescriptorEvent event) {
       // Do what you need here
    }
}
```

In order to use the class I could have used the @EntityListeners annotation on my entity class.  Unfortunately, this method would not allow Spring to control the creation of my listener and as a result would not allow for dependency injection.  Instead I added the following 'init' function to my class:

```
public void init() {
    JpaEntityManager entityManager = null;

    try {
        // Create an entity manager for use in this function
        entityManager = (JpaEntityManager) entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        // Use the entity manager to get a ClassDescriptor for the Entity class
        ClassDescriptor desc = 
            entityManager.getSession().getClassDescriptor(<EntityClass>.class);
        // Add this class as a listener to the class descriptor
        desc.getEventManager().addListener(this);
    } finally {
        if (entityManager != null) {
            // Cleanup the entity manager
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Add a little Spring XML configuration

```
<!-- Define listener object -->
<bean id="entityListener" class="EntityListener " init-method="init">
    <property name="injectedValue" value="Hello World"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
```

Now we have a situation where Spring creates a entity listener, injects it with whatever dependencies are needed, and the listener object registers itself with the entity class to which it intends to listen.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

I tested out the approach suggested in https://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/ and worked. Not very clean but does the job. Slightly modified AutowireHelper class for me looked like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AutowireHelper implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private AutowireHelper() {
    }

    public static void autowire(Object classToAutowire) {
        AutowireHelper.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(classToAutowire);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowireHelper.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then called this from entity listener like this:

```
public class MyEntityAccessListener {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;


    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(Object target) {

        AutowireHelper.autowire(this);

        myService.doThings();
        ...
    }

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@Lazy should do the trick

```
@Component
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

}
```

Comment: This one or Juan Jimenez answers work. At the end of the day, try to lazy initialize the bean. See my summary below

Answer (score 6):

The problem with JPA Listeners is that:

1. they are not managed by Spring (so no injections)
2. they are (or might be) created **before** Spring's Application Context is ready (so we can't inject beans on a constructor call)

My workaround to deal with the issue:

1) Create `Listener` class with public static `LISTENERS` field:

```
public abstract class Listener {
    // for encapsulation purposes we have private modifiable and public non-modifiable lists
    private static final List<Listener> PRIVATE_LISTENERS = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final List<Listener> LISTENERS = Collections.unmodifiableList(PRIVATE_LISTENERS);

    protected Listener() {
        PRIVATE_LISTENERS.add(this);
    }
}
```

2) All JPA listeners that we want to be added to `Listener.LISTENERS` has to extend this class:

```
public class MyListener extends Listener {

    @PrePersist
    public void onPersist() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

3) Now we can get all listeners and inject beans just after Spring's Application Context is ready

```
@Component
public class ListenerInjector {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshed() {
       Listener.LISTENERS.forEach(listener -> context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(listener));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer of Paulo Merson, here is a variation of how to set the SpringBeanContainer by utilizing `JpaBaseConfiguration`. Here are both steps:

**Step 1**: Define the listener as a Spring component. Note that autowiring works through constructor injection.

```
@Component
public class PliListener {

    private EvenementPliRepository evenementPliRepository;

    public PliListener(EvenementPliRepository repo) {
        this.evenementPliRepository = repo;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void touchForCreate(Object target) {
        // ...
    }

    @PostPersist
    void onPostPersist(Object target) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Set the `SpringBeanContainer`, which enables autowiring in the listener. [SpringBeanContainer JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html) might be worth a look.

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    protected JpaConfig(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        // configure use of SpringBeanContainer
        props.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, 
            new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));
        return props;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is because this listener bean is not under control of Spring.  Spring is not instantiating it, how can Spring know how to find that bean and do the injection?

I haven't tried on that, but seems that you can make use of AspectJ Weaver with Spring's Configurable annotation to have Spring control non-Spring-instantiated beans.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj

Comment: Hello and thank you Adrian. I have added `<context:spring-configured/>` to my configuration. I have aop*.jars in my POM. I don't think I am missing anything. Still `evenementPliRepository` is **null**. Any other idea of what I could be missing??

Comment: Do you have the agent started? quoted from the ref: `Further, in certain environments, this support enables load-time weaving without making any modifications to the application server's launch script that will be needed to add -javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar or (as we describe later in this section) -javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument-{version}.jar (previously named spring-agent.jar).`  But to be honest, I haven't really tried this feature before, probably there is other restrictions on this which I am not aware

Comment: I am going to check that. I am also realizing that because I use Spring Roo, `@Configurable` is already set up by Roo. What also strikes me is that I get no warning about dependency issues...

Comment: You can never get error on that, because, as I said, that object instance is not managed by Spring.  Having those DI-related annotations means nothing.  No one is going to look at those annotations to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 5.3 of Hibernate and version 5.1 of Spring (that's version 2.1 of Spring Boot), there's an easy solution.
No hack, no need to use AOP, no helper classes, no explicit autowiring, no init block to force injection.

You just need to:

1. Make the listener a `@Component` and declare the autowired bean, as usual.
2. Configure JPA in your Spring application to use Spring as the bean provider.

Here's how (in Kotlin)...

#### 1) Entity listener

```
@Component
class EntityXyzListener(val mySpringBean: MySpringBean) {

    @PostLoad
    fun afterLoad(entityXyz: EntityXyz) {
        // Injected bean is available here. (In my case the bean is a 
        // domain service that I make available to the entity.)
        entityXyz.mySpringBean= mySpringBean
    }

}
```

### 2) JPA datasource config

Get access to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in your application. Then add to `jpaPropertyMap` the following key-value pair: `AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER` => the application context's bean factory.

In my Spring Boot application I already had the code below to configure a datasource (boilerplate code found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa#javaconfig) for example). I only had to add the line of code that puts the `BEAN_CONTAINER` property in the `jpaPropertyMap`.

```
@Resource
lateinit var context: AbstractApplicationContext

@Primary
@Bean
@Qualifier("appDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
fun myAppDatasource(): DataSource {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = ["myAppEntityManagerFactory"])
fun entityManagerFactoryBean(builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
    val localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
            builder
                    .dataSource(myAppDatasource())
                    .packages("com.mydomain.myapp")
                    .persistenceUnit("myAppPersistenceUnit")
                    .build()
    // the line below does the trick
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.jpaPropertyMap.put(
            AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, SpringBeanContainer(context.beanFactory))
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

Create a service to make AplicationContext accessible:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.Setter;

@Service
class ContextWrapper {

    @Setter
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public ContextWrapper(ApplicationContext ac) {
        setContext(ac);
    }

    

}
```

Use it:

```
...    
public class AuditListener {

    private static final String AUDIT_REPOSITORY = "AuditRepository";
    
    @PrePersist
    public void beforePersist(Object object){
        //TODO:
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeUpdate(Object object){
        //TODO:
    }
    
    @PreRemove
    public void beforeDelete(Object object) {
        getRepo().save(getAuditElement("DEL",object));
    }
    
    private Audit getAuditElement(String Operation,Object object){

        Audit audit = new Audit();
        audit.setActor("test");
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        audit.setDate(timestamp);
        
        return audit;
    }

    private AuditRepository getRepo(){
        return ContextWrapper.getContext().getBean(AUDIT_REPOSITORY, AuditRepository.class);
    }
}
```

This class is created as a listener from jpa:

```
...
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
```

Since the listener is not under Spring's control, it can not access the context bean. I have tried multiple options (@Configurable (...)) and none has worked except to create a class that static access to the context. Already in that dilemma I think that this is an elegant option.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way is, in my opinion, to intervene into the process of instantiating of EntityListener.
This way significantly differs in Hibernate pre-5.3 versions and post-5.3 ones.

1) **In Hibernate versions earlier than 5.3** `org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.ListenerFactory` is responsible for EntityListener instantiation. The instantiation of this factory can be intercepted if you provide your own CDI-based `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager`. The CDI interfaces are (unnecessary for Spring DI world) verbose, but it's not difficult to implement Spring BeanFactory-backed CDI Bean manager.

```
@Component
public class SpringCdiBeanManager implements BeanManager {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public <T> AnnotatedType<T> createAnnotatedType(Class<T> type) {
        return new SpringBeanType<T>(beanFactory, type);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> InjectionTarget<T> createInjectionTarget(AnnotatedType<T> type) {
       return (InjectionTarget<T>) type;
    }
    ...
    // have empty implementation for other methods 
}
```

and the implementation of type-dependent `SpringBeanType<T>` will look like this:

```
public class  SpringBeanType <T> implements AnnotatedType<T>, InjectionTarget<T>{

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public SpringBeanType(BeanFactory beanFactory, Class<T> clazz) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T produce(CreationalContext<T> ctx) {
        return beanFactory.getBean(clazz);
    }
    ...
    // have empty implementation for other methods 
}
```

Now, the only thing left is to inject into Hibernate Configuration Settings our implementation of `BeanManager` under a property name `javax.persistence.bean.manager`. There are, probably, many ways to do so, let me bring just one of them:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SpringCdiBeanManager beanManager;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(){
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getJpaPropertyMap(){
                Map<String, Object> jpaPropertyMap = super.getJpaPropertyMap();
                jpaPropertyMap.put("javax.persistence.bean.manager", beanManager);
                return jpaPropertyMap;
            }
        };
        // ...
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }
}
```

Just remember that two things have to be Spring beans:
a) `SpringCdiBeanManager`, so that `BeanFactory` could be injected/autowired to it;
b) your EntityListener class, so that line `return beanFactory.getBean(clazz);` will be successful.

2) **In Hibernate versions 5.3 and later** things are much easier for Spring beans, as @AdrianShum very correctly pointed out. Since 5.3 Hibernate uses `org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.BeanContainer` concept and there is its ready-to-use implementation for Spring Beans, `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer`. In this case, just follow its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for people who find other answers are not summarized enough and for my future reference

cnmuc or Juan Jimenez answers work. At the end of the day, try to lazy initialize the bean. See my summary below

**cnmuc answer:**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeEntityListener {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeLogRepository repository;

    @PostUpdate
    @PostPersist
    public void postUpdate(Employee employee) {
        repository.saveAndFlush(new EmployeeLog(employee.getId()));
    }
}
```

**Juan Jimenez Answer:**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeEntityListener {
    static private EmployeeLogRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public void init(@Lazy EmployeeLogRepository repository) {
        EnrollmentEntityListener.repository = repository;
    }

    @PostUpdate
    @PostPersist
    public void postUpdate(Employee employee) {
        repository.saveAndFlush(new EmployeeLog(employee.getId()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it appears SpringBeanContainer is the way to wire up Spring to Hibernate's ManagedBeanRegistryImpl, which is responsible for creating instances of EntityListeners when Hibernate is creating it's callback objects. Calls to create beans are delegated to SpringBeanContainer which can create Spring beans with both constructor injection and autowiring. For example a EntityListener would look like

```
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    private MyBean myBean;
    public InquiryEntityListener(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    public MyEntityListener() {
    }
}
```

Note that the EntityListener does NOT require @Component annotation as this only creates an extra instance which is not used by Hibernate.

However when using SpringBeanContainer there are some important limitations and caveats that must be kept in mind. In our use case, instances of our EntityListener were created during the creation of Hibernate EntityManager. As this happened fairly early during the Spring lifecycle, many beans did not exist at this time. This led to the following discovery:

> The SpringBeanContainer will only autowire/constructor bean dependencies that exist at the time when the EntityListener is created. Constructor dependencies that don't exist will cause the default constructor to be called. Essentially there is a race condition when using SpringBeanContainer.

The work around for this is to inject a DefaultListableBeanFactory instance into the EntityListener. Later when the EntityListeners lifecycle methods are called (i.e. @PostLoad, @PostPersist, etc.) instances of the desired bean can be pulled out of the BeanFactory as the beans would've been created by Spring at this point.