# Spring Security in a multi module Maven project (where to put DB auth, UserDetails, etc.?)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, dependencies, multi-module

At the moment we have 6 Maven modules:

- `webapp`
- `security`
- `core` (provides database access to `User`)
- `common`
- `module1`
- `module2`

The dependency tree is pretty obvious I think:

- `webapp` depends on everything
- `security` depends on core
- `core` depends on common
- `common` depends on nothing
- `module1` depends on core and common
- `module2` depends on core, module1 and common

Now I'd like to have some `BaseEntity`: It should have a `@PrePersist` which saves the current `User`. Nearly every entity will use this `BaseEntity`. That's why every module depends on `core`.

And because everything depends on `core`, it seems logical to put this `BaseEntity` also in the `core` module. (even if I'd prefer to use `common` for this, but that seems impossible because of dependencies).

Now the problem occurs: To set the current User, I have to use access `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`. But with this I would have some unwanted dependency (or am I just too nitpicking?).

The problem get's even worse, if I want to have a custom implementation of `UserDetails`. Where should I put it? `core` or `security`? Or is it common to just let the `User` entity implement `UserDetails`? I don't think so. The question occurs, because when authenticating a user, I have to create the `UserDetails` object inside the `security` module. And when I want to retrieve the current `User` I'd have to cast the `getPrincipal()` method to the custom `UserDetails` class.

I'm really confused how to leave thing loosely coupled, but also achieve everything I need for the application.

The last idea that came to my mind was about using Dependency Injection, but I don't know if it works!? (Having a `currentUser` Bean inside the `security` module and everyone else can simply get it via `@Autowired MyCustomUserDetails`)

So please help me getting those things right!

Thank you! `:)`

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Can you provide any insights on the same if you were able to achieve this in some way. Will be helpful for a lot of people out there as it still seems to be a active issue which many people are facing and not finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is possible to have the code that injects the current user into `BaseEntity` to be in a different module (that the `core` module does not depend on), by putting the `@PrePersist` method in a separate listener class. To avoid adding the `@EntityListeners` annotation to the entity class (and therefore adding a dependency), you could configure the listener through XML. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655021/1374678).

Second, it appears to be quite a hassle to have dependencies injected into an entity listener, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447608/1374678). Therefore, I would simply stick to

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Since this code can be in the `security` module, I think it's not a big deal. If you worry about the cast to `UserDetails`, you could instead call `getAuthentication().getName()`, which directly returns the name of the principal (if available) and use that to look up the current user in the DB.

Finally, regarding letting `User` implement `UserDetails`: Of course, doing this will add a dependency to Spring Security again, so if you want to avoid that, then don't do it. Otherwise, I don't see any major issues with it, other than having methods in your class that you may not need (`isAccountNonExpired`, `isAccountNonLocked`...) and needing to cast to `User` when retrieving the principal. The advantage would be that you don't need to retrieve the user from the DB first.