# How can I add an entity listener to a JPA (EclipseLink) entity without an active session?

Tags: spring, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to do the following inside a spring bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void registerTorchEntityListeners()
{
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities())
    {
        if (entity.getJavaType().isAnnotationPresent(TorchEntityListeners.class))
        {
             TorchEntityListeners annotation = (TorchEntityListeners) entity.getJavaType().getAnnotation(TorchEntityListeners.class);
             for (Class listenerClass : annotation.value())
             {
                 Map<String, DescriptorEventListener> map = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(listenerClass);
                 for (DescriptorEventListener listenerBean : map.values())
                 {
                     session.getClassDescriptor(entity.getClass()).getEventManager().addListener(listenerBean);
                 }
             }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is I get the following exception because (I think) I am not in a transaction and therefore do not have a session available to grab the ClassDescriptor so that I can add a listener to a particular entity:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'torchEntityListenerConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
```

Basically I am trying to do the EclipseLink equivalent of this: http://invariantproperties.com/2013/09/29/spring-injected-beans-in-jpa-entitylisteners/. I would prefer to annotate the entity with the listener rather than doing something like this: [Injecting a Spring dependency into a JPA EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155632/injecting-a-spring-dependency-into-a-jpa-entitylistener).

Thoughts?

Comment: How do you currently inject the `EntityManager` in your bean ?

Comment: It was with: @PersistenceContext and that was my problem...yeah I know I didn't show that part...but I didn't realize that was this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I figure it out 30 minutes after I add a bounty :)

I finally got this to work by getting the entityManager from a wired in EntityManagerFactory instead of using: @PersistenceContext to inject it into the TorchEntityListenerConfigurer

Here is the working solution...and it works great!

Here is the config:

```
<bean id="approvalEntityListener" class="com.prometheus.torchlms.core.activity.approval.ApprovalEntityListener">
    <property name="activityRepository" ref="activityRepository" />
    <property name="notificationFactory" ref="notificationFactory" />
    <property name="notificationService" ref="notificationService" />
</bean>
<bean id="springEntityListenerConfigurer" class="com.prometheus.torchlms.core.SpringEntityListenerConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Here is where the magic happens (in case this is useful to someone):

```
public class SpringEntityListenerConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public SpringEntityListenerConfigurer(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerTorchEntityListeners()
    {
        //entityManager.
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities())
        {
            if (entity.getJavaType().isAnnotationPresent(SpringEntityListeners.class))
            {
                 SpringEntityListeners annotation = (SpringEntityListeners) entity.getJavaType().getAnnotation(SpringEntityListeners.class);
                 for (Class listenerClass : annotation.value())
                 {
                     Map<String, DescriptorEventListener> map = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(listenerClass);
                     for (DescriptorEventListener listenerBean : map.values())
                     {
                         ClassDescriptor classDescriptor = session.getClassDescriptor(entity.getJavaType());
                         if (null != classDescriptor)
                         {
                             classDescriptor.getEventManager().addListener(listenerBean);
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So now I can add my `@SpringEntityListeners({ApprovalEntityListener.class})` to any entity I want with any listener that I want and those listeners can be spring beans!

In case it helps here's the annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpringEntityListeners
{
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

Comment: Just a complement. You do not need to get an `EntityManager` : you can simply write `for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities())`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Great feedback. I will update the answer. I still need the EntityManager in order to get the Session so I can get the ClassDescriptor. Are you aware of another way to get a hold of that?

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can do your registrations without getting an EntityManager, because you only use it to get a client session, and you only use the client session to register listeners with the server session **without any direct interaction with the database** nor changing any object.

The `EntityManagerFactory` is actually an `EntityManagerFactoryImpl` that can directly expose the `ServerSession` with `unwrap`. I had to dig through classes explicitly marked as INTERNAL, to find that, and the `ServerSession` (also marked as INTERNAL) explicitely states in his javadoc : *All changes to objects and the database must be done through a unit of work acquired from the client session, this allows the changes to occur in a transactional object space and under a exclusive database connection*.

But for your use case, I think it is correct to use it like that, using the server session only to get access to the `Project` that actually contains the class descriptors and is a public class in EclipseLink :

```
public void registerTorchEntityListeners()
{
    // no entityManager here and Session is only used to get access to Project
    Project proj = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(Session.class).getProject();
    for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities())
    {
        if (entity.getJavaType().isAnnotationPresent(SpringEntityListeners.class))
        {
             SpringEntityListeners annotation = (SpringEntityListeners) entity.getJavaType().getAnnotation(SpringEntityListeners.class);
             for (Class listenerClass : annotation.value())
             {
                 Map<String, DescriptorEventListener> map = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(listenerClass);
                 for (DescriptorEventListener listenerBean : map.values())
                 {
                     ClassDescriptor classDescriptor = proj.getClassDescriptor(entity.getJavaType());
                     if (null != classDescriptor)
                     {
                         classDescriptor.getEventManager().addListener(listenerBean);
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this. Thanks for your help.