# JPA - Persist Class is not Entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA Project (Eclipse Link), works fine but I want to persist a class that is not Entity(Or Not entity in the same Persistence Context), currently I persist the reference id, and after that I do the call to retrieve the Object. I need know what is the best way to do that.. I do not want add code in the bean as listener event, because I want have a clean bean(constructos,properties, setters and getters without annotations),

My Idea is to extend the PersistenceContext(but, I do not know how to do it) adding a filter and identify the class to persist and doing something to replace the persistence of the class not mapped.

Any ideas or my question is out of place?

This is a Simple Example..

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

@Column
Integer id;

@Column
/*transient?*/
CustomerInfo customerInfo

/*setters and getters*/
}

/*this class maybe not be Entity.. Maybe be a Web Service Response Bean*/
public class CustomerInfo{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private BigDecimal balance;
   /*setters and getters*/
}
```

Comment: why not using an Embeddable ? It looks like what you want to do ...

Comment: @NoDataFound.. but I do not want save the CustomerInfo data.. I want persist only the reference to retrieve or save the CustomerInfo with a WebService Calling.

Comment: I assume that you CustomerInfo has some kind of key allowing you to retrieve it ? That key would be a reference you would need to pass each to the WS.

Comment: Yes, I have a key that I will pass to the WS.. But the WS returns more Information that I do not want to Persist. the CustomerInfo is going to have more fields on the time and is probably that this change frequently(all days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments: create an embeddable `CustomerInfoKey` with the essential information.

Two solutions then:

1. Inheritance:

   - Have `CustomerInfo` inherits `CustomerInfoKey`
   - Use `setCustomerInfoKey(customerInfo)` with `customerInfo` a `CustomerInfo`.
2. Composition and delegation:

   - Have a field `CustomerInfoKey key` in `CustomerInfo`
   - Delegate the getter/setter of `CustomerInfoKey` in `CustomerInfo`:

     ```
     public Foobar getFoobar() {return key.getFoobar()}
     public void setFoobar(Foobar foobar) {key.setFoobar(key);}
     ```
   - Have a method getKey() and use it to persist data; you can even create a setter taking a `CustomerInfo` in `Customer` and doing the appropriate stuff.

I don't know how JPA implementations behave when it encounters partial mapping like solution #1. But it should work.

Comment: Looks well.. but I do not understand, I do not see. how could setting the another properties retrieved from WS call in the CustomerInfo. The properties I need to add after call all findById Or query..

Comment: Could you clarify your question with examples: do you want to do some lazy loading like `customer.getCustomerInfo()` instead of something like `customerInfoService.findById(customer.getCustomerKey())` ? Also explain if you use Spring, CDI, etc because you'll still need to inject/get a `customerInfoService` to do the work.

Comment: Hi NoDataFound, you gave me the Idea to resolve, I Share the solution If you Can Check if you think that is a Good Way..

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by [NoDataFound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023553/nodatafound) in the comment, if you do not want to add an Id, an [Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)/[Embedded](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html) tandem could be the solution: because of the Id problem, you should have the data in the same table (it is possible to keep different classes). You have the doc in the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#gjiwz). If you don't want to change the code, you could use the XML for object/relational mapping. In the [wikibook about JPA](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables) you have an XML sample.

Comment: when I say that I do not want to add code in my Bean.. I refer that I do not want add PrePersist, PostPersist, or similar annotation, etc with annotations or with XML, I want add the PostPersist event maybe On an External class, Manager, Listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I am creating a `EntityListener`:

```
public interface JREntityListener<T> {
    public Class getTarget();
    public void postUpdate(T t) throws Exception;
    public void postCreate(T t) throws Exception;
    public void preMerge(T t) throws Exception;
    public void postMerge(T t) throws Exception;
    public void prePersist(T t) throws Exception;
    public void postPersist(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

I am Created a Class to Catch the events of a Entity

```
public class JRDescriptorEventListener<T> implements DescriptorEventListener{
  //implements all methods of DescriptorEventListener
  //i am Show only One to Example
  @Override
  public void postClone(DescriptorEvent descriptorEvent) {
    //        descriptorEvent.getObject();
    try {
      logger.info("postClone");
      t.postUpdate((T) descriptorEvent.getObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }   
}
```

I am created a Binding `EntityListener` with `PersistenceContext` (Thanks [jhadley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660911/jhadley) by [injecting a spring dependency into a JPA EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155632/injecting-a-spring-dependency-into-a-jpa-entitylistener)):

```
public void addListener(JREntityListener t) {
    JpaEntityManager entityManager = null;
    try {
        // Create an entity manager for use in this function
        entityManager = (JpaEntityManager) entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        // Use the entity manager to get a ClassDescriptor for the Entity class
        ClassDescriptor desc =
                entityManager.getSession().getClassDescriptor(t.getTarget());
        JRDescriptorEventListener jrDescriptorEventListener = new JRDescriptorEventListener(t);
        desc.getEventManager().addListener(jrDescriptorEventListener);
        logger.info("Entity Listener for " + t.getTarget().getCanonicalName() + " is added");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (entityManager != null) {
            // Cleanup the entity manager
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am implements the Listener addind Listener

```
javoraiPersistenceBase.addListener(myEntityListener);

public class MyEntityListener implements JavoraiEntityListener<Customer> {

     @Autowired
     CustomerSvc customerSvc;


     @Override
     public Class getTarget() {
         return Customer.class;
     }

     @Override
    public void postUpdate(Customer customer) throws Exception {
      CustomerInfo customerInfo = globalDataSvc.findCustomerInfoById(customer.getCustomerInfo().getId());
      customer.setCustomerInfo(customerInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't say it's bad or good, but I'm pretty much against dependency injection in an entity. It think it makes it too complicated for the advantages it brings (also, I quite don't understand your real need, perhaps I would simply called a dedicated service for that when I need it, instead of doing implicitly [or unobviously], without even knowing if it would be useful).

Comment: EntityListener is not an Entity, I add the customerSvc for complete the additional info of CustomerInfo, but Maybe is some complicated.