# How to set @CreatedDate in the past (for testing)

Tags: spring, jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa

My **spring-data-jpa** backend has a class that populates the (test) database with a lot of test data. The class usese the spring data repositories to create entities. All my entities have a field annotated with `@CreatedData` and the corresponding `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` annotation on the model class. This works fine so far.  dateCreated is automatically set correctly.

But when running **Junit test** I sometimes need to create a (test) object with a dateCreated in the past. How can I archive this?  Only via plain JDBC?

Comment: The (not) quick and dirty way: `Thread.sleep(1000)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12155632/476716

Comment: I need CreatedDate  a month in the past :-)    Thank you for the link. I already feared that a spring solution would be "large".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way that works for me (using plain JDBC):

First I create my domain objects for testing with spring-data-jpa:

```
MyModel savedModel = myRepo.save(myModel);
```

That automatically fills the "dateCreated" with timestamp of "now". Since I need creation dates in the past for testing I manually tweak them with plain JDBC:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

[...]

// This syntax is for H2 DB.  For MySQL you need to use DATE_ADD
String sql = "UPDATE myTable SET created_at = DATEADD('DAY', -"+ageInDays+", NOW()) WHERE id='"+savedLaw.getId()+"'";
jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
savedModel.setCreatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - ageInDays* 3600*24*1000);
```

Do not forget to also setCreatedAt inside the returned model class.

Answer (score 7):

In case you are using Spring Boot, you can mock dateTimeProvider bean used in EnableJpaAuditing annotation. Spring Data uses this bean to obtain current time at the entity creation/modification.

```
@Import({TestDateTimeProvider.class})
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "testDateTimeProvider")
public class SomeTest {

    @MockBean
    DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;

...
```

It is necessary to define actual testDateTimeProvider bean, but it won't be used at all, as you will use mock instead.
You can write mockito methods afterwards as usual:

```
@Test
public void shouldUseMockDate() {

    when(dateTimeProvider.getNow()).thenReturn(Optional.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0)));
    
   
   ... actual test assertions ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The best and cleanest way I found using Mockito is to change the AuditingHandler before saving by sating your worn implementation of DateTimeProvider. Since Java 8 this can be done using Lambda Interfaces like this:

```java
@SpyBean
private AuditingHandler auditingHandler;

// inside the test
auditingHandler.setDateTimeProvider(() -> Optional.of(YOUR_DATE));
savedEntity = repository.save(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exact test case which you are using, but i can see few solutions:

- create a mock object, once the dateCreated is called return date
  month ago
- maybe use in-mem db, populate it with date before test
- go with AOP from the link provided in comments

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions:  MockObjects:  I need hundrests entries each with different creation dates in my DB.   InMemoryDB: That is what I am using. I populate it with my TestDataCreator.java    I am creating my testdata in java (instead of plain sql in a data.sql  file) because I need  to juggle a lot of references between the test data entries.