# Dependencies not Autowired when using an xml Entity Listener

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am currently working on a project where I need to audit my Entities. To do this we are using an *Entity Listener* configured in an xml file (This was required by the architecture of the project, no annotations were allowed) :  [see this documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events)

We are also working using *DDD (Domain Driven Design)* so our application is using Domain/Application/Infrastructure layers and also WebApp (The latter allows you to start the application and do requests on it).

Here is my entity configuration :

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd" >
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener class="com.company.infra.application.service.impl.MyServiceASImpl">
                    <post-persist method-name="handlePostPersist"/>
                    <post-update method-name="handlePostUpdate"/>
                    <pre-remove method-name="handlePreRemove"/>
                </entity-listener>
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

This is actually working. The methods located in *MyServiceASImpl* are correctly called. The problem is that the different services available as `@Autowired` are not injected correctly and I get a null pointer exception when they are used.

Here is the code of MyServiceASImpl :

```
package com.company.infra.application.service.impl;
// ... Different necesssary imports
@ApplicationService // This is a custom annotation
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) // To propagate exceptions
public class MyServiceASImpl implements MyServiceAS {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceASImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private com.company.domain.service.MyServiceDS mysServiceDS; // This is in the domain layer

    @Autowired
    private TransversalService transversalService;

    @Autowired
    private com.company.domain.model.myRepository myRepository; // Interface in domain layer but implementation in infrastructure layer

    // ... Other methods

    public void handlePostPersist() {
        // Calls to on of the services
    }

    public void handlePostUpdate() {
        // Calls to on of the services
    }

    public void handlePreRemove() {
        // Calls to on of the services
    }
}
```

I have several xml configuration to do *component-scan* on the necessary packages.
Furthermore, if this service is called from a webservice contained in the *webapp* layer, the dependencies are injected correctly.

But, when the Entity Listener is triggered and class theses, all three dependencies are *null*.

Has anyone encountered this problem ? How can autowire the dependencies correctly ?

Don't hesitate to ask for more details.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the entity listener is not managed by Spring, you cannot use `@Autowired`. So you need to use a static injection:

```
public class MyServiceASImpl implements MyServiceAS {    

    public void preRemove(final Object objet) {
        ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyRepository.class)
            .gererAuditCasPreSuppression(objet);
    }
}
```

Make sure to modify your xml file in order to call the methods.

You will have to right an application context provider :

```
package leclerc.wrf.commun;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    protected ApplicationContextProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextProvider.context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ApplicationContextProvider.context;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but this will not work because the entity listener is managed by JPA and the Spring dependency injection will not work.

Please have a look at the solutions mentioned here:

[Injecting a Spring dependency into a JPA EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155632/injecting-a-spring-dependency-into-a-jpa-entitylistener)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. @Sébi11 answer and yours are more than enough.