# Modifying model during serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I using spring boot and I have an Entity that store path of a URL and because of domain address could be changed in the future, I didn't store full URL into the database.
Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestModel
{
    private String urlPath;

    @Transient
    private String fullUrl;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

I need to concat domain address with `urlPath` and store its value into `fullUrl` field during serialization model.
I know I can do this in getter method of the `fullUrl` field, But domain address should be read from the configuration and model should not have anything about the business logic.
what is the best practice to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Use @PrePersist, @PreUpdate annotations.
See for example https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

If your business logic to modify the value lives in an 
external bean you can use @EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
and use @PrePersist, @PreUpdate annotations there.

As those entitylisteners classes are not beans but POJOs
to autowire external beans into them you may use one of the strategies
mentioned here: [Injecting a Spring dependency into a JPA EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155632/injecting-a-spring-dependency-into-a-jpa-entitylistener) to get your business logic beans autowired into those entitylisteners.