# Hibernate 4.1 with Spring 3.1.0 unable to register event listeners in web application

Tags: spring, hibernate

In the thread below, it was discussed how to register event listeners in hibernate with spring:
[eventlisteners using hibernate 4.0 with spring 3.1.0.release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616146/eventlisteners-using-hibernate-4-0-with-spring-3-1-0-release)

I've my Integrator in the file as mentioned in thread which is registering event listeners.

```
META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

This works fine when I run the code in a main program (with eclipse). However, when I am deploying my application as a war in tomcat, the Integrator never gets called. Inside tomcat this file is present at location:

```
webapps/ROOT/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

Can somebody please take a look?

I tried running a JUnit test case with test application context to replicate the scenario, but here the Integrator gets invoked.

On debugging further, Noticed that the following peice of code in Hibernate is adding Integrators:

```
public IntegratorServiceImpl(LinkedHashSet<Integrator> providedIntegrators, ClassLoaderService classLoaderService) {
    // register standard integrators.  Envers and JPA, for example, need to be handled by discovery because in
    // separate project/jars.
    addIntegrator( new BeanValidationIntegrator() );

    // register provided integrators
    for ( Integrator integrator : providedIntegrators ) {
        addIntegrator( integrator );
    }

    for ( Integrator integrator : classLoaderService.loadJavaServices( Integrator.class ) ) {
        addIntegrator( integrator );
    }
}
```

Inside this, classLoaderService.loadJavaServices( Integrator.class ) is unable to find my custom Integrator when my application is deployed in tomcat, while it does in test case or while running standalone.

Comment: Do you deploy your webapp as ROOT application? what happens if you put `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` under `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/META_INF/services`?

Comment: what if you put it in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator ?

Comment: Yes, the webapp is deployed as ROOT, and I tried both the options $CATALINA_HOME/lib/META_INF/services and webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/. They don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've used the other idea mentioned in the thread which is a code based approach:

```
@PostConstruct
public void registerListeners() 
{
    EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(
        EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT).appendListener(listener);
registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE).appendListener(listener);
}
```

A config based approach, however will be more helpful.