# Updating a singleton object using Spring & Hibernate on database update

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to update a singleton object ( which is loaded by spring on application startup using the bean definition ) . This object is however loaded with entries from a table in a database ( MySQL ).

This table can be updated from time to time through the application.

Is it possible to update the singleton object using spring and hibernate when a row in the database is updated ?

Comment: If the data it contains is small enough to be kept in memory, loading the state from the database every time it's needed shouldn't be a problem. You can always use the 2nd-level cache if really needed.

Comment: I don't understand your meaning by saying "table can be updated through the application", is the application means other function from same vm? Or is it means another vm or host may write  the table  at same time? If the changes comes from another vm or host, your current object is already dirty. You'll have to load them from database everytime to keep it same to database, as @JBNizet suggested.

Comment: I'm required to update the table through the application using other functions on the same vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate event listeners:

1. Check how to add event listeners to your [Session Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616146/eventlisteners-using-hibernate-4-0-with-spring-3-1-0-release).
2. You can listen on entity persist/merge/flush events. Because the event listener is a Spring object you can inject the reference to your singleton.
3. Once you intercept the wanted event, you can update the singleton state with the latest updated data.

Comment: Which will only work in a single application. If you have multiple application modifying the same data you won't get those events.

Comment: The question says "This table can be updated from time to time through the application."

Comment: With PostgreSQL you can get [database notifications](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-notify.html) but he's using MySQL instead. Another workaround is to use JMS to link events and the singleton update.

Comment: A database notification is still not an event you can handle with hibernate or jpa events and if I'm not mistaken requires work on the database side (you will need some code to trigger the `NOTIFY`). If it is a single application one could still use the 2nd level cache as that could be either updated automatically or you could invalidate the element in the cache. No need to hack around with an event listener and try to figure out the correct object.

Comment: We are on the seam wave-length. A distributed 2nd level cache will work if it supports custom callbacks. Oracle supports [advance queueing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) but for MySQL I'd probably go for a [CQRS architecture](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).