# Custom Listener Definition in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote a Custom Listener.
But when i tries to set it in Hibernate Configuration as in

```
Configuration configuration=new Configuration().setListener("save-Update",XYZClass);
```

It states that there is no function with the name setListener.
Help me out what am i doing wrong.
My Hibernate Version id 4.02

Comment: That is not valid Java code. Invoking a constructor needs parentheses: `new Configuration()`.

Comment: I am using with the Braces sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: The Issue is still i can't acces the method setListener() but ih Hibernate Documentation it is stated that setListener() is a valid function

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the documentation of Hibernate 4.x? Could you provide the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate 4.x](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) do not have `setListener` method, this method is available in [Hibernate 3.x](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setListener%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) version only.

In Hibernate 4.x you can use interceptors, go through this link for details:

[Chapter 14. Interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch14.html)
[Hibernate interceptor example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)

This SO post has some details on how to use Listeners in Hibernate 4.x, you can have a look at this:

[eventlisteners using hibernate 4.0 with spring 3.1.0.release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616146/eventlisteners-using-hibernate-4-0-with-spring-3-1-0-release)