# BeanCreationException hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean Bean property 'EL' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating from Hibernate 3/Spring 3 to Hibernate 5/Spring 4 and am receiving this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'sessionFactory-ETL' defined in class path resource 
[config/context-hm.xml]: Error setting property values; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid 
property 'eL' of bean class 
[org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 
'eventListeners' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the 
parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Here is part of the config file:

```
   <bean name="hibernateEventListeners" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="pre-update" value-ref="pup" />
            <entry key="save-update" value-ref="xSaS" />
            <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="xIS" />
            <entry key="merge" value-ref="xML" />
            <entry key="pre-delete" value-ref="eRUL" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory-ETL"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="eventListeners" ref="hibernateEventListeners" />
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?  I'm not sure if I need to change the type of the hibernateEventListeners to something other than a MapFactoryBean.

Comment: Please, don't use strange names like `sessionFactory-ETL`, `hEL`.

Comment: So do you have an answer?

Comment: @Andreas See if this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616146/eventlisteners-using-hibernate-4-0-with-spring-3-1-0-release

Comment: Hi Madhusudana, This may work but I cannot use Annotations.  I have to do this via xml.

Comment: according to the docs, `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` does not have a property `heL` nor anythin close to this...

Comment: my mistake ... it should have been eventListeners

Comment: there is no such property, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html