# Run method before every method call of HttpServlet

Tags: java, reflection, aop

I'm writing an abstract Tomcat servlet, `Foo` and I want to make it so that whenever a method is called in `FooImplement`, it runs a method from `Foo`.

So before every method call in `FooImplement` I want to run `checkAccess` defined in `Foo`. If the user does not have access, the method is not invoked and the request is redirected elsewhere. If the user does have access, the method is invoked.

I thought I could use a Proxy as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121513/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-make-every-method-in-a-class-start-with-a-certain-blo) but the problem is I cannot pass tomcat the proxy instance because that would involve an impossible constructor of

```
public Foo() {
    return (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
    new Class[]{this.getClass()},
    new FooInvocationHandler(this);
}
```

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: Can't you use a ServletFilter?

Comment: @Jaumzera the filter runs on doGet and doPost. I want to run my checkAccess method when the implementations of doGet and doPost call other methods. The reason for this is access is defined using an annotation on the method (e.g. `deleteUser`). Therefore I can't filter on that high of a level I don't think.

Comment: @Jaumzera I tried implementing something like this and I can't see how it could be done.

Comment: Hey @DontTurnAround, have you seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576918/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-invocation-with-standard-java-features-no-aspectj-e

Comment: I don't think that works @Jaumzera because there's no way to make Tomcat use an instance of the proxy instead of the Servlet.

Comment: So try to implement your own version of HttpServlet to do what you want. You can put your code inside META-INF/services in order to make Tomcat use it instead of the original source. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692497/tomcat-wont-load-my-meta-inf-services-javax-servlet-servletcontainerinitializ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html.